# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when using webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to lunch my course project on the brave browser using `webpack-dev-server --mode development --https --open` but I am constantly getting this "Your connection is no private" error with "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID". I have absolutely no clue of what this is.

I tried:
 - Removing the --https tag 
 - Changing the createCertificate.js file in the webpack-dev-server folder on the node_modules, adding this lines:

```
{
    name: 'extKeyUsage',
    serverAuth: true,
    clientAuth: true,
    codeSigning: true,
    timeStamping: true,
  },
```

- Sometimes this error doesn't happen but now its stuck and I can't continue my work

Answer (score -2):

That's what your software should do if it's presented with a certificte that is not signed by a trusted entity. That's what ssl is for (among other things).

Solutions:

1. get a certificate signed by a trusted CA (ok, don't do this right now)
2. get your client to accept the cert or just make it ignore certificate errors (but be aware that this makes the client prone to man in the middle attacks!)
3. make your own Root-certificate, use this to sign the cert of your server and add your own root cert to the client.

Best, read up on self signed certificates. As a starting point i'd suggest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate